# Trying to find the median in my code, if check doesn't seem to work?

Tags: c++

Even if the amount entered ends up being an even amount of elements my code skips the if check. It is probably something silly I missed or didn't notice in the chapter I was reading. Thanks for taking a look at it.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        vector<double> num;
        double numb;

        while(cin>>numb)
            num.push_back(numb);

        sort(num.begin(), num.end());

        if(num.size() <= 2)
            cout << "Need more data." << endl;
        else if (num[num.size()%2] == 0)//even?
        {
            cout << "Median is: " << num[num.size()/2] << endl;
            cout << "Median is: " << num[(num.size()/2)+1] << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Median is: " << num[num.size()/2] << endl;

        keep_window_open();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to use this test:

```
num[num.size()%2] == 0
```

To see if your vector is of even length.  But that's not what it does - it checks the *value* at either `num[0]` or `num[1]` to see if it's zero.

You want:

```
 num.size() % 2 == 0
```

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even think about that. It was so obvious. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

The line `num[num.size()%2]` will either check element `0` or `1` depending on the size of `num`.  What you mean is to check is wether the length of `num` is even or odd, which is `num.size() % 2`.  So your check becomes:

```
      else if(num.size() % 2 == 0)//even?
```